# Java Runtime Execute SQL script continue on SQL error

Tags: java, mysql, sql, process, runtime

We are trying to write a java code which will perform a product upgrade steps. One of the steps is to call a execute a sql script file.

We are using java runtime process executor to call the sql script.
Thing is sometimes when the product is patched before upgrade a couple of tables which get created through sql script are already created.
And the process execution fails with Table already exists error.

We would like the process to not fail on any SQL related error and simply continue on next statement(Similar to how it behaves if calling the sql script using mysql console).

We have tried but couldn't find a solution to this. Please help us if it is possible and how?

This is how the SQL script starts:

---

```
USE iiq;

create table iiq.spt_monitoring_statistic(
id varchar(32) not null,
name varchar(255),
created bigint,
modified bigint,
operation varchar(255),
source varchar(255),
```

Code to call process:

```
    Process p;
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

    String c4 = "cmd /c cd "+input_Map.get("DBServerHome")+"/bin"+" && 
    echo exit | mysql -u "+UpgradeRequest.dbUser+" - 
    p"+UpgradeRequest.dbPass+" < " +'"'+iiq_dir+"/identityiq/WEB- 
    INF/database/upgrade_product_tables.mysql"+'"';

    p=rt.exec(c4);

    stdout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                         p.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = stdout.readLine()) != null) {
                log.warn(line);
            }
```

Error I Got:

> ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 11: Table 'spt_monitoring_statistic'
>   already exists

Edit: Changing the sql script will be hard as it is part of the product upgrade package and this is not our product. We are just upgrading the same. We just want to somehow ignore the error and make the processing go to next line. If we run the sql script using mysql console it shows error but continues to next lines and executes them. Can we somehow do the same using java runtime?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a different table name as the error clearly shows table with the above name already exists.

Comment: Hi Thanks. Changing the sql script will be hard as it is part of the product upgrade package. We just want to somehow ignore the error and make the processing go to next line. If we run the sql script using mysql console it shows error but continues to next line and executes it. Can we somehow do the same using java runtime?

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 11: Table 'spt_monitoring_statistic'
>   already exists

This means the table is already exists in your database and you executed this query many times.

You should add `IF NOT EXISTS`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS iiq.spt_monitoring_statistic(
id varchar(32) not null,
name varchar(255),
created bigint,
modified bigint,
operation varchar(255),
source varchar(255),
```

Or delete first table then execute above query:

```
DROP TABLE iiq.spt_monitoring_statistic
```

If you want to create more than one tables then change your table name as @Himanshu said

Comment: Hi Thanks. Changing the sql script will be hard as it is part of the product upgrade package. We just want to somehow ignore the error and make the processing go to next line. If we run the sql script using mysql console it shows error but continues to next line and executes it. Can we somehow do the same using java runtime?

Comment: @user3008362 If you want to ignore the error and make the processing go to next line then surround your query code with `try{...}catch(Exception e){}` statements